# Find array object by given field value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Assume there are two arrays like this:

```
const element = ['abc', 'def']`

const total = [
  { _id: 'foo', something: 'else' }
  { _id: 'abc' },
  { _id: 'bar' },
  { _id: 'def' }
]
```

I need to find the element items in the total array and return the index value.
So the result should be

```
[1, 3]
```

I thought of using a loop and look up with indexOf, but that is not the correct way:

```
element.forEach(e => {
  total.indexOf(e)
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original test of `total.indexOf(e)` doesn't search for the object with its `_id` property value being `e` - it searches for whether the object equals the `'abc'` or `'def'` string, which is of course never true.

Instead, you can use `reduce`:

```js
const element = ['abc', 'def'];

const total = [
  { _id: 'foo', something: 'else' },
  { _id: 'abc' },
  { _id: 'bar' },
  { _id: 'def' }
];

const foundIndicies = total.reduce((a, { _id }, i) => {
  if (element.includes(_id)) a.push(i);
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(foundIndicies);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map over `element` with a variable `e`, and use [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) on the `total` array to find the index of the first dictionary that contains `e` as one of its values, which you can retrieve using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const element = ['abc', 'def'];

const total = [
  { _id: 'foo', something: 'else' },
  { _id: 'abc' },
  { _id: 'bar' },
  { _id: 'def' }
];

const locations = element.map(e => total.findIndex(d => Object.values(d).includes(e)))

console.log(locations);
```